# GET request from a browser and my server has to respond with a php output

Tags: php, linux, multithreading, webserver

I have a multithreaded webserver and I need it to be able to respond on .php file requests with a php output in linux.

The language I'm using in C/C++ and I don't understand how to use php on that request.

Comment: Please elaborate. I can't tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: When I get a request from the browser with a ".php" extension I need to create a child process to interpret the ".php" file and send the output to the browser , using one of the exec functions maybe?